# Проблема с safari

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите как заставить safari, чтобы оно принимало данный стиль:

```css
header{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 141px, 100% 125px, 100% 0%, 0% 0px, 0px 125px);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 141px, 100% 125px, 100% 0%, 0% 0px, 0px 125px);
}
```

На андроид все нормально работает:[линк на скрин андроида](https://prnt.sc/l9v1n8) , а в сафари на разрешении меньше 767 в шапке большой отступ: [линк на срин в сафари на iphone6](http://prntscr.com/l9v435)

Comment: Загрузи картинки в сам вопрос. И сниппет переделай. Тем более, в сафари clip-path работает - я ещё в 9м его использовал.

Comment: изменю но позже- жутко болит голова

Comment: странно, что у вас работает... почему у меня не срабатывает?

Comment: Может, проблема вообще не в clip-path? Как пройдёт голова, составьте полноценный ([но минимальный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) пример, чтобы мы могли запустить его в своих сафари и увидеть проблему

Comment: вот линк http://cis.dtraduga.vh55.hosterby.com/
Интересует именно шапка, как и писал в самом начале. Непонятно почему не срабатывает в сафаре на ios :(

Comment: не дождался ответа, очень срочно надо было решить вопрос. Для разрешений <767 просто сделал бэкграунд картинкой. Но опять же странно - на десктопе в сафари все хорошо  работает и clip-path и polygon а на малых разрешениях с мобилы нет. То ли я что-то намутил, толи реально какой-то баг.